# JQuery - Most elegant way for storing data to be used by javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, storage

I was just curious what's the best way to store data for use by JQuery - I'm setting up a basic mp3 player, and the title, artist, track and file name all need be held somewhere to be retrieved by JQuery upon clicking in the radio interface. I was thinking of storying them as simple attributes within an  tag, like this:

```
<a href="{song_file}" data-title="{song_title}" data-artist="{song_artist}" data-album="{song_album}">
```

but I'm guessing that might be considered bad form. I know I could bring them in via XML, but I'd rather not have to retrieve from some external document. Anybody have a good solution?

Comment: "Most elegant" and "best" way?  This is begging to be closed as subjective.  Define your measures for elegance and "bestness".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is jQuery's `.data()`: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/

Here is one possible way it can be done:

```
<div id="songs"></div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    jQuery(function() {

        // The following array can be trivially generated directly from your data,
        // by PHP's json_encode(), or your language's equivalent:
        var songs = [
            {
                file: '/path/to/song.mp3',
                title: 'A Day in the Life',
                artist: 'The Beatles',
                album: 'Sgt. Pepper\'s Lonely Hearts Club Band',
            }
            // ...
        ];


        var wrap = jQuery('#songs');
        for (var i=0, ii=songs.length; i<ii; i++) {
            jQuery('<a></a>')
                .text(songs[i].title)
                .attr('href', songs[i].file)
                .data('song-data', songs[i])
                .click(click_handler)
                .appendTo(wrap);
        }

        // then, you can retrieve the data like this:
        function click_handler() {
            var data = jQuery(this).data('song-data');
            alert('Album was: '+data.album);
            return false;
        }

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you could send them using a json string and then converted to an object.

Answer (score 1):

I think the use of `data-*` attributes is appropriate.

Alternately you can put the title, artist and album as spans within the anchor tag. Something like this:

```
<a href="/url/of/purple-rain.mp3">
  <span class="title">Purple Rain</span>
  <span class="artist">Prince</span>
  <span class="album">Purple Rain</span>
</a>
```

And then style those spans to look the way you like - maybe even hiding some of the data.

Answer (score 1):

data- notion is acceptable and is the preferred way especially for HTML5 of attaching data to markup. However are the Anchors actually being used for anything else? I would be simply having the data output as JSON something along the lines of

```
var MP3TrackData = [{TrackName ='something'}];
```